# Wordpress dashboard are not visible after hosting on webhost (database issue)

Tags: php, database, wordpress, web-hosting, wp-admin

My WordPress site was successfully running on localhost, then I moved it to the web-hosting platform, and configured the required minor changes and the site started working.
But the problem occurred when i tried to login to the wp-admin.
After I signed-in, the **dashboard, pages, widgets, etc** options are not showing under wp-admin bar when I hover over **wp-admin-bar-site-name**.
Even after clicking wp-admin site-name, I am not able to open dashboard.
Any help from Experts is appreciated.

Images for your relevance.

[image]
Mouse hover over profile icon.

[image]
Mouse hover over **wp-admin-bar-site-name**.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change the z-index of the logo?

Comment: I can guess, that you dont have administrator permissions

Comment: @Samvel Aleqsanyan I created that site and it was running fine on localhost but now I'm not able to access the dashboard after importing all the contents to the webhost.

Comment: @Saifer Yes I changed the z-index of the logo and it was working fine with that on localhost.

Comment: Did you try to disable the z-index in the developer console? Does it work?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that but that didn't worked for me. In fact z-index is not set for the logo..